# How to use antlr to create SQL Select Query parser?

Tags: java, sql, antlr

i am using [squiggle](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=squiggle%20sql&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=https://code.google.com/p/squiggle-sql/&ei=4UWbUoTONYTDswaN84DoDw&usg=AFQjCNG99D9xXWCCjUDqDh10ShTxkS2qyw&bvm=bv.57155469,d.Yms) to create dynamic select queries for postgresql, in one point of my application i need to reverse engineer the created select query and extract columns, tables, joins, orders,group by and .... from it, i googled a bit and found [general sql parser](http://www.sqlparser.com/)  which meets my demands but i need an open source solution to be able to modify it as i wish, i googled a bit more and read some where that i need antlr to write my own parser like fellas in hibernate did. the question is i don't know how to use it and not able to find an easy to understand example. the more important question is, considering scope of problem ( a select query) do i really need antlr to do this? 
thank you

Comment: Do you really need to parse the query at all, seeing as it's you who is generating the query in the first place? Seems like a roundabout way to go about it!

Comment: if i want to be able to edit the generated query i have two options . first to store the string query and then when i need to edit it i parse it. second to store bunch of objects that i am using to generate the query (like column and table)

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use for example JSqlParser (github/jsqlparser). It comes with examples of extracting tablenames.

Comment: can JSqlParser  be used commercially for free?

Comment: It has a commercial compatible license. JSqlParser is dual licensed under LGPL V2.1 or Apache Software License, Version 2.0